# Invalid Login Attempt on my computer - Asp .NET MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My ASP.NET MVC Application always logged me in successfully so far. I started developing it three months ago. It is now deployed in production and the intended users are using it without problem.

However, I'm the only one having trouble logging in on my local machine. It keeps rejecting me with this message : "**Invalid Login Attempt**".

Here is the code in my controller. As you can see, I have modified the regular login by replacing Email with Username in PasswordSignInAsync - it always worked fine until a few days ago (possible explanation later in this post). My Usernames and Email are different and always have been. (I changed the ApplicationUser model in that way too.)

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
...
            var user = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);

            if (user != null)
            {

                var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
// This is where my login is rejected. Result always equals SignInStatus.Failure.

                if (result == SignInStatus.Success)
                {
                    if (!user.IsPasswordChanged)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction(nameof(ManageController.ChangePasswordFirstConnection), "Manage");
                    }
                }

                switch (result)
                {

                    case SignInStatus.Success:
                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                        return View("Lockout");
                    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                        return RedirectToAction(nameof(SendCode), new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                    case SignInStatus.Failure:
                    default:
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Login Attempt.");
                        return View(model);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unknown user.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }
```

The only change I have made on my computer that might have created this issue is **changing the system language**. For some reason, the language was English (I'm in France and therefore use French). So around the period of time when the problems started, I finally changed it to French. I'm not 100% sure that this trigged the problem, but I'm suspecting something about that change.

I tried a few things, like reverting back to English, and forcing the CultureInfo to EN-gb or EN-us by adding this line in the Login method : 
`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");`
But no change.

I am using Entity Framework Code First to create my sample users for development. Here is the code in the Seed method in Configuration.cs for each user.

```
 var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(store);
            var result = manager.Create(
                new ApplicationUser
                {
                    Id = "29409b9c-10be-42eb-9f9f-245d22e505bc",
                    Email = "xxxxx@xxxx.fr",
                    UserName = "Name",
                    LockoutEnabled = true,
                    EmailConfirmed = false,
                    Roles = { new IdentityUserRole { RoleId = "da3cfd23-a233-430f-bdc9-7a9f86ae1f58", UserId = "29409b9c-10be-42eb-9f9f-245d22e505bc" } }
                }, "tempPass!1");
```

It does create the users properly.

I have the feeling I am missing something important here.

Do you have any ideas to help find the problem ? 
Do you have experience on the consequences on an ASP.NET application of changing the language ? 
Do you know how exactly SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync works ? I have looked up the [asp.net GitHub repository](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/SignInManager.cs) but didn't see something there that would help.

Comment: So is it working in dev environment?

Comment: Yes... for everyone but me !

Comment: What are you getting in result? You might have changed something in authentication for deploying to prod

Comment: Result always equals SignInStatus.Failure when I'm on debug. I can't find a way to have a more detailed error...

Comment: check that the user name is the same as the email you are passing in.

Comment: It's not - I use different user names. That way we can say "hello [username]" instead of an email. That's why I slightly changed the default PasswordSignInAsync login method, which usually uses the email, and now takes the username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that everything was working fine.

By writing manually the login and password and not using the password manager (Chrome) at all, I finally managed to log in. I can't tell whether I kept using a wrong password (which I think is unlikely but still possible) or if there was a problem due to the language change.